# Discord.py - How would I remove a certain character from a variable?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have a command which allows you to create a channel and a role based on what the user gives. The problem arises when the channel name is over a word. For example:

`>newrealm Space Invaders (emoji) (mention)`

This command will raise an error because now it's assuming "Invaders" is the emoji.

Which is why I am now using something like this:

`>newrealm Space-Invaders (emoji) (mention)`

Now the problem with this command is that while creating the role, the name is `Space-Invaders OP`. Is there a way to remove the `-` in the role's name?

My code:

```py
@commands.command()
  @commands.has_permissions(manage_roles = True)
  async def newrealm(self, ctx, realm, emoji,  user: discord.Member):
    author = ctx.message.author
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    channel = ctx.message.channel
    color = discord.Colour(0x3498DB)
    role = await guild.create_role(name= realm + " OP", color = color)
    category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name = "Realm Channels List Test")
    await category.create_text_channel(realm + "-" + emoji)
    await ctx.send("Created Channel and Role!")
    await user.add_roles(role)
```

Any suggestions or tip's would help a lot!

Comment: have you tried using your command like this `>newrealm "Space Invaders" (emoji) (mention)`

Comment: If the question is just "how do i replace a hyphen with a space in a string?", consider using str.replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options that would solve this problem:

1. encase the name in quotes so the function recognizes it as one argument.
2. receive the name last with a special syntax:

```py
async def newrealm(self, ctx, emoji,  user: discord.Member, *, realm):
```

The second method is more elegant but it is not in order, the first method is less elegant because of the quotes but it is in order, Choose your preference.